# Can't add 1+1 in ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Since some updates of ipython and efforts to install R in jupyter I just can't even add 1 and 1: 
`1+1` just yields no output in a python notebook (jupyter).

The console from where the notebook is launched indicates some problem with IPKernel App ...

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 16:15:44.792 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jeanpat
[I 16:15:44.792 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:15:44.792 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 16:15:44.792 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

(process:11705): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
[I 16:15:50.325 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 50c937a7-9ab6-456f-8e65-6d7de55301a6
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: ipython.widget
[I 16:17:50.327 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
```

However 1+1 yields 2 if executed in an ipython console:

```
~$ ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: 1+1
Out[1]: 2
```

Comment: Do you have 4.0 of all the things ? Imho the comm-target should just be a warning as widgets are optional.

Comment: I have installed ipython with sudo pip install -U ipython[all] and sudo pip install jupyter, so i suppose that yes

Comment: Hum the no-such com is not critical I checked. Do you have errors in the JS console of the browser ?

Comment: no error : "Kernel ready"

Comment: When looking in the network tab of the console,I found the follwing error: SyntaxError:JSON.parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: That's weird. Open an issue on jupyter/notebook on GitHub, we can debug that there it will be easier. Point back to here so that we can update with an answer later.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `~/.local/share/jupyter` fixed the problem. Running with the debug mode (jupyter notebook --debug) showed where jupyter was looking for its kernels. –  Jean-Pat 2 hours ago